# Make a div resize when i zoom out

Tags: html, css

I have a div that doesn't shrink when I shrink the page.
I state that the div contains a div for the image, which must be 65% of the width of the parent div, and a div for the content, which must be 35% of the width of the parent div.
How can I do?

**Page with zoom 30%**
[image]

If you look, the div below has shrunk, while the one above did not, it kept its height.
I would like him to scale down like the others.

Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```css
#categorie {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#categorieImg {
  width: 65%;
}

#categorieImg img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#categorieContent {
  width: 35%;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#categorieContent h3 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#categorieContent button {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="categorie">
  <div id="categorieImg">
      <img src="../img/bg-poster.jpg" alt="Immagine delle categorie">
  </div>
  <div id="categorieContent">
      <h3>Le categorie</h3>
      <pre>
      Concerti:
          Questa è la nostra più grande categoria dove si possono trovare i biglietti per i concerti di tanti generi, tra cui il Pop & Rock, Jazz, Metal e anche i biglietti per i festival.

      Sport:
          Questa è la categoria per gli amanti dello sport, in cui si possono acquistare i biglietti per seguire la propria squadra del cuore in svariati sport: Calcio, Tennis, Basket, Rugby, Formula 1 e MotoGP.

      Mostre e musei:
          Questa è la categoria per gli amanti della cultura e a chi piace l'arte in ogni sua tipologia. Abbiamo i biglietti per le mostre d'arte e di storia, nonchè anche per i musei e siti archeologici.

      Teatro:
          Questa è la categoria per chi vuole godersi uno spettacolo che potrà essere un Musical e varietà, Prosa, Teatro lirico, Cabaret, Balletto classico e moderno oppure concerti di musica classica.
      </pre>
      <button class="acquistaHome">Acquista biglietti</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using the `img` element inside the `categorieImg` div, so the size of `categorieContent` inside the `categorie` div will be the same as the minimum `img` height

If you want the `img` on the left to resize depend on the `categorieContent` size on the right, you need to remove the `img` and change it to `background` as updated below

```css
#categorie {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#categorieImg {
  width: 65%;
  background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/41/6a/12/416a12455b40de67fb2825ce9985fb7e.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/*#categorieImg img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}*/

#categorieContent {
  width: 35%;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#categorieContent h3 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#categorieContent button {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="categorie">
  <div id="categorieImg">
  </div>
  <div id="categorieContent">
    <h3>Le categorie</h3>
    <pre>
      Concerti:
          Questa è la nostra più grande categoria dove si possono trovare i biglietti per i concerti di tanti generi, tra cui il Pop & Rock, Jazz, Metal e anche i biglietti per i festival.

      Sport:
          Questa è la categoria per gli amanti dello sport, in cui si possono acquistare i biglietti per seguire la propria squadra del cuore in svariati sport: Calcio, Tennis, Basket, Rugby, Formula 1 e MotoGP.

      Mostre e musei:
          Questa è la categoria per gli amanti della cultura e a chi piace l'arte in ogni sua tipologia. Abbiamo i biglietti per le mostre d'arte e di storia, nonchè anche per i musei e siti archeologici.

      Teatro:
          Questa è la categoria per chi vuole godersi uno spettacolo che potrà essere un Musical e varietà, Prosa, Teatro lirico, Cabaret, Balletto classico e moderno oppure concerti di musica classica.
      </pre>
    <button class="acquistaHome">Acquista biglietti</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also add `background-position` style to determine which position of the image will be shown